# Is it possible to ignore a file on the server and not reset it when deployed to Heroku?

Tags: python, git, heroku, telegram-bot

I'm developing a Telegram bot to push from an RSS feed to my channel. I have a file to save the published articles to the channel, but when I change something and deploy in heroku the file is reset and all posts are sent to the channel again.

My question is: Is it possible to ignore a file on the server and not reset it when deployed to Heroku?